# SQL query - Find all couples of actors who has played EXACTLY in the same movies

Tags: sql, group-concat

I am practicing for the database exam I have shortly but I can't figure out how to make this query.

I copy paste the excercise as it is:
Given 2 tables

```
FILM(Title, Director, Year, Genre)
InCastOf(Actor, Film) Where InCastOf(film) is constrained to Film(Title)
```

Write a query to find all couples of actors who have played EXACTLY in the same movies.

What I got so far is:

```
SELECT InCastOf.Actor AS A1, T.Actor AS A2, InCastOf.Film FROM InCastOf
JOIN (SELECT Actor, Film FROM InCastOf) AS T ON InCastOf.Film = T.Film
WHERE  InCastOf.Actor != T.Actor
```

Which returns me for each film a pair of actors who played in it. I could use group by etc to nail down the query, but the word "Exactly" is causing me some trouble because I need to make sure those actors only worked on the same movies and nothing else. At least that is what I understand from the word "Exactly".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you could accept some false hits, you could use CHECKSUM_AGG on Film ID per Actor. Then find two actors with the same checksum.

Comment: "Fasle Hits" doesn't seem to go with "Exactly".

Comment: That is a good point.

Comment: you could use `GROUP_CONCAT` or equivalent in your DBMS with the same concept though

Comment: the GROUP_CONCAT Thing got me really really close, I only have one problem now, it returns A1, A2, GROUP_CONCAT(FILM) and there are quite a few duplicate of the typle actorA, actorB, [x, y, z] and actorB, actorA, [x, y, z] which are actually the same but DISTINCT obviously doesn't work. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @Martin Smith I wrote the query as following:

```
SELECT T1.Actor AS A1, T2.Actor AS A2, T1.films FROM (
    SELECT Actor, GROUP_CONCAT(Film) AS films
    FROM InCastOf 
    GROUP BY Actor) AS T1
JOIN (
    SELECT Actor, GROUP_CONCAT(Film) AS films
    FROM InCastOf 
    GROUP BY Actor) AS T2 
ON T1.films = T2.films
WHERE T1.Actor > T2.Actor
```